# mysql databases different in terminal & workbench on osx

Tags: php, mysql, macos, laravel, phpmyadmin

I use `mysql -u root -p` to connect to MySQL on my osx terminal. It works fine and I can create and view databases.

But these databases are completely different to the ones I can see on MySQL workbench an phpmyadmin. The ones of the latter two are the same.

how do I open the MySQL databases that I can see on my terminal on a workbench or any other gui?

also when I connect my Laravel to a db,

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=somedb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD='abcd'
```

it connects to the dbs on mysql terminal, but not the ones on phpmyadmin & workbench.

DO i have to different sqls running? .. And how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you using MAMP or something similar? I have experienced this before, where MAMP comes with it's own internal copy of mysql running inside the MAMP container.

Comment: Yes you'll have different MySQL instances running. Have you installed MAMP or something like that?

Comment: Yes im running MAMP

Answer (score 0):

I think this command can help you to check if there are two instances of MySQL running on your machine or not.

```
ps aux | grep mysqld
```